# Is there something special about the normal distribution in the context of the random vector being equally likely to point in any direction?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, regression

In the context of the error vector $$\epsilon: \Omega \to \mathbb R^n$$ of a multivariable regression, I have heard roughly the following:

> The distribution of $\epsilon$ is uniform over the angle, so the random vector is equally likely to point in any direction. Distributions other than the Gaussian one don't give a spherically symmetrical distribution.

As far as I can tell, it says that the multivariable normal distribution can be characterized in this way. It made me very curios. I was looking for a proof and saw [this](http://www.utdallas.edu/~serfling/papers/ess5011.pdf):

> Among spherically symmetric distributions are not only multivariate normal distributions with covariance matrices of form $σ^2I$ but also, for example, certain cases of standard multivariate t and logistic distributions.

So the first quote is wrong and there is nothing special about normal distribution in this regard?

Comment: Indeed, nothing special, a PDF $f$ is spherically symmetric if and only if $f(x)=g(\|x\|)$ for some function $g$, for example, $$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{c}{1+(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}$$ defines a spherically symmetric, non gaussian, PDF on $\mathbb R^2$, for some suitable $c$.

Comment: Consider a uniform distribution on the interior of the unit circle centered at the origin (or in higher dimensions, _unit ball_). Spherically symmetrical, not normal.